# Can't use Mockito when and thenReturn

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I'm trying to write mockito when method so that when a method is called then I can define a returned data. java method:

```
 when(myRepository.insertNote(any(Note.class))).thenReturn(returnedData);
```

In **kotlin** I'm trying to write the same but it's not showing me the option to write **thenReturn()** after **when()**. I'm trying:

```
 when(mainRepository.fetchApiresultFromClient(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyInt()) )
        .thenReturn(returnedData)
```

how do i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `doReturn` and then `when` as mockito best practice:

```
doReturn(returnedData).when(mainRepository)
.fetchApiresultFromClient(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), 
    ArgumentMatchers.anyInt());
```

Comment: Thanks . Can you also please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/q/59461795/5700215